# Bitcoin Mining using an iPhone?

Tags: mining-technical-details, mining-setup

Is it possible to start Bitcoin mining using an iPhone with 4G internet connection?
Storage is not an issue,or is it?
(Mine is 256GB).

Comment: In principle you could, but in reality the processing power is way too small. So you wouldn't have a chance to find a block before others do. Mining is done today on specialized hardware.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to start Bitcoin mining using an iPhone with 4G internet connection?

Yes. It is theoretically possible to start mining with an iPhone.
Your internet connection is almost completely irrelevant and your space is also not important. The important thing is the power of your CPU.

**But:** Mining with an iPhone means mining with CPU. And that's completely unprofitable. Even mining with GPU is not profitable anymore because of all the ASICs. You would fight against big mining pools and you would probably never be the first one who gets a hash with 20 zeros. So, you would waste a lot of energy and don't get any reward. Not worth it!

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically it is possible, but in reality, cryptos are mined either by multiple fast GPUs (e.g. 1.5 USD daily income per GTX1080Ti minus the electricity costs) or by special equipment made only for the purpose of mining (ASICs). These devices are much, much faster and better suited for mining than an iPhones CPU. So in reality, you would need multiple years of work done by your iPhones CPU just to receive a tiny, tiny fraction of a bitcoin.

There is however one special cryptocurrency which is suited for mining by mobile CPUs: Electroneum. You can download the app and start mining with little effort and get some fractions of a cent per day at the current low prices. However, you should know, that even that is only a fake mining as the Electroneum coins you receive have already been premined and you only get a reward for wasting electricity with your mobile phone. Its simply a marketing move to "simulate" how it is to mine cryptocurrency and you can read it in Electroneums whitepaper.

TLDR: Forget mining of cryptocurrencis with CPUs in general, doesnt matter if mobile or desktop.